# Mix CASE and IN in sql query

Tags: mysql

I've read the other questions but I don't think they happen to be 'exactly' like my situation.

What I want to do is a query similar to `SELECT ... WHERE some_field_to_compare IN (CASE WHEN something something THEN ('1','2','3') ELSE ('0'))`

So that the query can turn out to be `SELECT ... WHERE some_field_to_compare IN ('1','2','3')` or `SELECT ... WHERE some_field_to_compare IN ('0')` depending on `something something`. How can this be done? Thank you very much...

EDIT: as alex requested!! :))

`SELECT cake FROM cakes WHERE cake_magic_number IN (CASE WHEN cake_frosty = 'no_frosty' THEN ('1','2','3') WHEN cake_frosty = 'is_frosty' THEN ('1','2') WHEN cake_frosty = 'wow... good frosty!' THEN ('2') ... END)`

Comment: that is my prefered pseudocode `I want something to do something when something but not something` :-) If you put some real values of SOMETHING that would help everybody a lot :-)

Comment: @Alex I updated the code! I really do hope this tiny bit of important information will guide you to the response!!!! :)

Comment: where is `ELSE` part?

Comment: Not needed @Alex. If it works with ELSE it should work without ELSE :)) My cake code has no ELSE, only THENs :)

Comment: So @Alex did my enhanced code help you find the answer?

Comment: wait 5 min, I'll return with solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa3aa/1

```
SELECT *
FROM cakes 
WHERE 
  CASE 
    WHEN cake_frosty = 'no_frosty' AND cake_magic_number IN (1,2,3) THEN 1 
    WHEN cake_frosty = 'is_frosty'AND cake_magic_number IN (1,2) THEN 1 
    WHEN cake_frosty = 'wow... good frosty!' AND cake_magic_number = 2 THEN 1
  ELSE 0
  END
```

or imho more compact variant I prefer:

```
SELECT *
FROM cakes 
WHERE 
  IF(cake_frosty = 'no_frosty' AND cake_magic_number IN (1,2,3),1, 
    IF(cake_frosty = 'is_frosty'AND cake_magic_number IN (1,2),1, 
       IF(cake_frosty = 'wow... good frosty!' AND cake_magic_number = 2,1,
       0)
    )
  )
```

or even just OR as GordonLinoff said:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa3aa/3

```
SELECT *
FROM cakes 
WHERE 
  (cake_frosty = 'no_frosty' AND cake_magic_number IN (1,2,3))
  OR (cake_frosty = 'is_frosty'AND cake_magic_number IN (1,2))
  OR (cake_frosty = 'wow... good frosty!' AND cake_magic_number = 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `or`:

```
when (<something> and some_field_to_compare IN ('1','2','3') ) or
     (not <something> and some_field_to_compare IN ('0'))
```

Comment: what if there are several conditions?

Comment: @fane . . . Then you put in the appropriate logic.